# My prefix will despite a fact, My infix will negatively react

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

- My prefix will despite a fact
- My suffix tells what to do instead
- My infix will negatively react
- My whole is an idea in your head

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Thought

My prefix will despite a fact

> **Though** = "despite the fact that"

My suffix tells what to do instead

> **Ought** = "used to indicate duty or correctness"

My infix will negatively react

> **Ugh** = "exclamation used to express disgust or horror"

My whole is an idea in your head

> **Thought** = "an idea or opinion produced by thinking, or occurring suddenly in the mind"

Comment: Ahh, now the wording makes sense. Great job as always :)